# Attaching 1 validating event handler to Multiple textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, event-handling

**OverView**

I have researched out there an I know there is a vast amount of info subscribing multiple event handlers to a single event however, I have not been able to apply it to my scenario.  Pretty much I have a bout 30 of these `validation event` handlers from a `textBox`, all doing he same process. Below is one of those handlers:

```
  private void txt_HouseName_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        { // Convert User input to TitleCase After focus is lost.

            if (Utillity.IsAllLetters(txt_HouseName.Text) | !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_HouseName.Text))
            {
                errorProvider.Clear();
                txt_HouseName.Text = Utillity.ToTitle(txt_HouseName.Text);
                isValid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                errorProvider.SetError(txt_HouseName, "InValid Input, please  reType!!");
                isValid = false;

                //MessageBox.Show("Not Valid");
            }

        }
```

How would I minimizes my code to just one of these lines of code and only have one of these event handler? 
I know I should attach them within the designer code something similar to this

```
this.txt_Fax.Validating += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.txt_Fax_Validating);
```

But as they are `textboxes` How would I go about attaching 1 `validating events handlers` to all of my `TextBoxes`

Answer (score 3):

You should be using the `object sender` parameter. as the sender is nothing but the object that called the **Event Handler**. So, have a global event handler and attach the same handler to all the text boxes. Your Event handler will look something like this.

```
private void txt_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        { // Convert User input to TitleCase After focus is lost.

          //Cast the sender to a textbox so we do not need to use the textbox name directly
            TextBox txtBx = (TextBox)sender; 
            if (Utillity.IsAllLetters(txtBx.Text) | !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBx.Text))
            {
                errorProvider.Clear();
                txtBx.Text = Utillity.ToTitle(txtBx.Text);//using the cast TextBox
                isValid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                errorProvider.SetError(txtBx, "InValid Input, please  reType!!");
                isValid = false;

                //MessageBox.Show("Not Valid");
            }

        }
```

Since the `object sender` parameter is passed with almost every event, it makes it easy to have a common callback for similar events and just check the sender and perform specific operations.

Comment: Also you might want to make `sender` to a `TextBox`, instead of an `Object`, so your intellisense can work properly. Basicly remove `TextBox txtBx = (TextBox)sender;`  and work with `sender` directly, but thats optional.

Comment: @Luke that wont work as EventHandler's signature is `(object,EventArgs)` a TextBox can be cast to an object because TextBox inherits from object but not vice versa. The suggested edit will give a `no matching overload` error.

Comment: Does it? Works great for me tho. Using it all the time in VB.NET. Is it a VB.NET/C# difference or one of the option strict - changes?

Comment: Yes C# employs more Type-Safety than VB I guess, If you try attach the event handler to some other control that is not a TextBox in VB, that will give an exception during run-time. Which does not happen in C#@Luke

Comment: Good point. Didn't know about that. You win :-) #NoMoreChatInComments